# Not every row is shown in a query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to calculate the number of transactions and the number of payments in my table. These counts are based on data in separated tables. I need to group the results by year and the week of year. The dates are coming also from a separate table. I add the week values in an union of the payments and transactions in a with clause and do afterwards the calculation.

```
WITH CHART_DATES
AS (
    SELECT DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
    FROM DIM_DATE DD
    RIGHT JOIN FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP ON DD.ID = FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID
    GROUP BY DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR

  UNION

    SELECT DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
    FROM DIM_DATE DD
    RIGHT JOIN FACT_AS_BALANCE FAB ON DD.ID = FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID
    GROUP BY DD.CAL_YEAR, DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
  )
SELECT
  CD.WEEK_OF_YEAR,
  CD.CAL_YEAR,
  COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT FPP.ID), 0) AS PAYMENTS,
  COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT FAB.ACCOUNT_STATEMENT_ID), 0) AS STATEMENTS
FROM FACT_PAY_PAYMENT FPP
RIGHT JOIN DIM_DATE DD ON FPP.REQUESTED_EXECUTION_DATE_ID = DD.ID
FULL JOIN FACT_AS_BALANCE FAB ON DD.ID = FAB.BALANCE_DATE_ID
RIGHT JOIN CHART_DATES CD ON DD.CAL_YEAR = CD.CAL_YEAR
  AND DD.WEEK_OF_YEAR = CD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
INNER JOIN DIM_AS_CHARACTERISTICS DAC ON FAB.BALANCE_TYPE_ID = DAC.ID
WHERE DAC.TRANSACTION_INTRADAY_FLAG = 'N'
GROUP BY CD.CAL_YEAR, CD.WEEK_OF_YEAR
```

I added following data in my tables:

> Week 42 of 2015 has 1 payment and 2 transactions
>
> Week 41 of 2015 has 1 payment and 0 transactions

After executing the query, I receive following result:
[Wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Oe8.png)

What is wrong in my query and how to fix it?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: your query is grouping by week and year and you show that you are expecting 2 weeks in your results but your result image only shows 1 row.  maybe inner join to DAC is removing one of your weeks?

Comment: Look at the difference between UNION and UNION ALL - UNION will perform a distinct selection